# Не устанавливаются плагины в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

> Warning: Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Возможно, что-то не так с
>   сайтом WordPress.org или с настройками вашего сервера. Если проблема
>   не решится, обратитесь на форумы поддержки. (Не удалось установить
>   защищённое соединение с WordPress.org. Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с
>   администратором сервера.) in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite1\wp-admin\includes\plugin-install.php on
>   line 158
>
> Something went wrong with the plugin API.

В чем проблема? Куда копать?

Comment: в сообщении же сказано, что копать в настройки сервера

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно изменить права доступа, а также групу для папки на локальной машине `wp-content/plugins` .

Если локалка, то можно и установить 0777 , при перемещении на хостинг 0755. 
Также, чтоб не спрашивало доступи ftp в `wp-config.php` добавить строчку:

`define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`